# Using a section as abstract in latex template

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc

I want to create a markdown report with an abstract that can include figures generated by the report itself. The usual way of defining the abstract as a string in the yaml header doesn't work for me.

Essentially, I want to have some part of the document with something like this:

````
## Abstract

Lorem impsum this is the abstract

```{r, fig.cap = "figure in the abstract"}
plot(pressure)
```
````

And then have something like this in the latex document

```
\begin{abstract}
Lorem impsum this is the abstract 
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{unnamed-chunk-1-1.pdf}
\caption{figure in the abstract}
\end{figure}
\end{abstract}
```

Ideally, this would be done by having something like

```
\begin{abstract}
$body.abstract$   
\end{abstract}
```

In the latex template. But the problem I'm facing is that for Pandoc, everything that is rendered by knitr is part of the `$body$` variable, so I don't know how to access the content of a specific section.

As a workaround, creating a separate `abstract.Rmd` file that compiles into a latex fragment and then using

```
\begin{abstract}
\input{abstract.tex}
\end{abstract}
```

works. But it involves remembering to compile that file first, and pollutes the directory with an extra LaTeX file. Since that will certainly will be a source of errors and confusion for the expected users, I'd like to avoid it.

Is what I'm asking for possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the [abstract-to-meta](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/abstract-to-meta) [Lua filter](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/articles/lua-filters.html) should do exactly what you need.

> This moves a document's abstract from the main text into the metadata.

Download the `abstract-to-meta.lua` file and place it into your project directory next to the R Markdown file. Then make sure that it is called by adding a `pandoc_args` field to your metadata:

```yaml
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: ["--lua-filter=abstract-to-meta.lua"]
---
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. As a workaround I had created something very similar in R.